Getting Hikvision camera view in WPF
I have a Hikvision camera. I need to get images from this camera in my application. All SDK examples are made with winform and I am trying to integrate it into wpf. In the sample SDKs given, picturebox is used and the handle parameter of pictureBox is connected to the image.
lpPreviewInfo.hPlayWnd = mtbDate.Handle;

I added a PictureBox using WindowsFormsHost in WPF, but no image appears. When I press the Live button, the RAM increases in the background. I think this is proof that the image is being received, but I cannot see the image.
Login works smoothly.
private void Login(string ipAddress, int port, string username, string password)
{
    CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 DeviceInfo = new CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30();
    m_lUserID = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_Login_V30(ipAddress, port, username, password, ref DeviceInfo);

    if (m_lUserID < 0)
    {
        iLastErr = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError();
        str = "NET_DVR_Login_V30 failed, error code= " + iLastErr;
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Success!");
    }
}

It doesn't give any errors in Live, but I can't see the video either.
private Int32 m_lRealHandle = -1;
CHCNetSDK.REALDATACALLBACK RealData = null;
private void LiveView()
{
    if (m_lUserID < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please login the device firstly");
        return;
    }

    if (m_lRealHandle < 0)
    {
        CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO lpPreviewInfo = new CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO();
        lpPreviewInfo.hPlayWnd = myImage.Handle;
        lpPreviewInfo.lChannel = 1;
        lpPreviewInfo.dwStreamType = 0;
        lpPreviewInfo.dwLinkMode = 0;
        lpPreviewInfo.bBlocked = true;
        lpPreviewInfo.dwDisplayBufNum = 1;
        lpPreviewInfo.byProtoType = 0;
        lpPreviewInfo.byPreviewMode = 0;


        if (RealData == null)
        {
            RealData = new CHCNetSDK.REALDATACALLBACK(RealDataCallBack);
        }

        IntPtr pUser = new IntPtr();

        m_lRealHandle = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(m_lUserID, ref lpPreviewInfo, null/*RealData*/, pUser);
        if (m_lRealHandle < 0)
        {
            iLastErr = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError();
            str = "NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40 failed, error code= " + iLastErr;
            MessageBox.Show(str);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
    return;
}

public void RealDataCallBack(Int32 lRealHandle, UInt32 dwDataType, IntPtr pBuffer, UInt32 dwBufSize, IntPtr pUser)
{
    if (dwBufSize > 0)
    {
        byte[] sData = new byte[dwBufSize];
        Marshal.Copy(pBuffer, sData, 0, (Int32)dwBufSize);

        string str = "ÊµÊ±Á÷Êý¾Ý.ps";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(str, FileMode.Create);
        int iLen = (int)dwBufSize;
        fs.Write(sData, 0, iLen);
        fs.Close();
    }
}

The design code is as follows.
   <StackPanel>
  
       <WindowsFormsHost>
           <wf:PictureBox x:Name="myImage"
                          Width="500"
                          Height="500"
                          />
       </WindowsFormsHost>
       <Button Content="Login"
               Click="Login_Click" />
       <Button Content="Live View"
               Click="Live_Click" />
   </StackPanel>

Note: It never falls into the RealDataCallBack function. Images can also be taken in the original winform code without triggering RealDataCallBack.
I think the problem is not being able to display the image. There is a Record function in the SDK. When I want to record, it successfully takes the record and writes it to the relevant file path. The code is as follows.
        bool m_bRecord = false;
    private void btnRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sVideoFileName;
        sVideoFileName = "Record_test.mp4";

        if (m_bRecord == false)
        {
            int lChannel = 1;
            CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_MakeKeyFrame(m_lUserID, lChannel);

            if (!CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_SaveRealData(m_lRealHandle, sVideoFileName))
            {
                iLastErr = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError();
                str = "NET_DVR_SaveRealData failed, error code= " + iLastErr;
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(str);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                m_bRecord = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_StopSaveRealData(m_lRealHandle))
            {
                iLastErr = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError();
                str = "NET_DVR_StopSaveRealData failed, error code= " + iLastErr;
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(str);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                str = "Successful to stop recording and the saved file is " + sVideoFileName;
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(str);
                m_bRecord = false;
            }
        }

        return;
    }


null/*RealData*/ are you sure that should be commented out? If you can get access to the raw pixelbuffer you can use a WriteableBitmap to copy the pixels data to. A pictureBox in a formHost should also work, but you need to update it somewhere, I can't see that being done anywhere in your example.

The example provided by Hikvision is exactly the same if you replace the line with "lpPreviewInfo.hPlayWnd = myImage.Handle;" If I remove it in winform, I cannot get the image there either. It's updating here somehow, but I have no idea how.

When I open RealData, yes the data comes, but the data seems very inconsistent, sometimes 40 bytes, sometimes 20 bytes, sometimes 5000 bytes. I'm not sure how to convert this to an image.

@JonasH What do you mean by update? How should I update?

Data comes first in the form of 20 bytes and then in byte packages ranging from 800-5000. Like 20-2500-20-1520-20-3555.

The problem seems to be in my pictureBox. When I want to upload a normal image, I cannot see the image.

Winforms need to be informed what to draw, and when to redraw. One way to do this is by setting the Image-property of the picturebox. It is possible that the library does this for you if you hand over a reference or handle to the picturebox. But I'm not at all familiar with the library you are using, so I can be of little help there. If you want to check if the problem is in the wpf/winforms integration you could try subscribing to the invalidated and/or paint events of the picturebox, that might tell you something at least.

myImage.Image = new Bitmap("filePath"); When I do this now, I still cannot display the image, but when I take the myImage.Image object, convert it to BitmapSource and assign it to WPF's own Image object, I can display it there.

Then you might want to simplify your example/question to be "minimally reproducible". If you know the issue is with the picture box or WindowsFormsHost there is no need to involve the hikvision library, except possibly as background information.

I solved the problem. I opened a .Net Core project and added usewindowsforms, eliminating any reference addition. I'm not sure why I'm having such an issue with .Net Framework. Maybe there was a problem with the dlls I added.

I understood the source of the problem. It doesn't matter whether the project is .NET Framework or .NET Core. Interestingly, if AllowsTransparency="True" is set in the application, WindowsFormsHost will not work. You can access the details from the link below.
Must be;
AllowsTransparency="False"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/troubleshooting-hybrid-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#opacity-and-layering
